# Angular universal cannot resolve relative url in scss files

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, sass, angular-universal

I am transferring my existing angular app to universal, to make it more seo friendly. I did all it according to these guides [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering), [official angular site](https://angular.io/guide/universal). It compiles and starts express server, but throws error `ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'footer-bg.png'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'footer-bg.png'`, which is related to background url link in my scss file.

What should I do to resolve assets links properly for angular universal?